# How to Handle 503 Response from Server in Ember Application?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, http-status-code-503

How to handle `503` response from the server in my `ember` application?  How to debug as a UI Developer? How UI Developer can Handle these kinds of response.

Comment: Please Verify and upvote the answer if you find it useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ember provides default `error handlers` which will be fired when appropriate error substate is found.

For instance: If the route's `model` hook returns an `error` payload (an error response from the server), the error event can be handled and used to display an error message, redirect to a page, etc.

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findAll('privileged-model');
  },

  actions: {
    error(error, transition) {
      if (error.status === '403') {
        this.replaceWith('login');
      } else {
        // Let the route above this handle the error.
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Reference - https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

(OR)

You can handle it directly when the promise is resolved using `.then`,

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.findAll('privileged-model').then((response) => {
    // handle success
  }, (response) => {
    // handle error
    if (response.status === '403') {
      // handle 403 errors
    }
  })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

ember provides its internal error handler. So it doesnt matter what error your api sends you back ember will always produce the same error message.  "Invalid adapter". If you want to show the original messages from your api response you need to stringfy your response. e.g `JSON.stringify(response.errors)` .